# Place number on predefined marker shapes on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using predefined google markers (circular shape). I want to place number (between 1-100) on this marker but I am unable to do so.

I have checked this link http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|FE6256|000000  but it will show number on pinned marker.
Is there any way I can pass my circular marker to google chart api

Here is the code for my marker:

```
var markerIcon = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: '#000',
    fillOpacity: .9,
    scale: 10,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 1
  };

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: markerIcon,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
        map: map,
    });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/developer_fiddle/cy55boru/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cy55boru/6/ try this for a start. Its not round but it will give you a starting point. Now according to the pin you place on a map, let's say with number 45, change the text parameter to 45:      icon :"http://dummyimage.com/32x32/000/fff&text=45". Also you can create your own marker creator, with round icon and PHP+GD. Pass a parameter to the url, get it with $_GET["text"] and output it with header('');

Answer (score 2):

As of v3.21 (currently the 'experimental' version, v=3.exp), [labelled markers are supported natively by the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels).

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cy55boru/8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var params = {
     'lat': $('#map_canvas').data('lat'),
     'long': $('#map_canvas').data('long')
   };
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(params));

 });


 function initialize(coordinates) {
   var mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.lat, coordinates.long),
     zoom: 15,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

   var markerIcon = {
     path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
     fillColor: '#000',
     fillOpacity: .9,
     scale: 10,
     strokeColor: '#000',
     strokeWeight: 1
   };


   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     icon: markerIcon,
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.lat, coordinates.long),
     map: map,
     label: {
       color: 'white',
       text: '1'
     }
   });

   marker.setMap(map);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px;height:300px" data-lat='40.8152' data-long='-73.0455'></div>
```